# multiple url rewriting mod

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two pages say

```
http://assistque.com/services.php?prod_id=35&prod_url=Operating%20System%20–%20Windows
```

and

```
http://assistque.com/sub_services.php?sp_id=13&sp_url=Technical%20Support%20For%20KASPERSKY
```

i wrote two rules for two different pages but the for the second page it uses first rule .

Please help

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /services.php?prod_id=$1&prod_url=$2 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /sub_services.php?sp_id=$1&sp_url=$2
```

Comment: do i need to modify the url as <a href="../13/Technical%20Support%20For%20KASPERSKY">Technical Support</a>

Im doing it this way.. 
or Should not change the url and keep it as
<a href="sub_services.php?sp_id=13&sp_url=Technical%20Support%20For%20KASPERSKY">Kaspersky</a>

Answer (score 0):

This is because the patterns in the both rules are the same, try changing them into something unique:

```
RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /services.php?prod_id=$1&prod_url=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^subservice/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /sub_services.php?sp_id=$1&sp_url=$2 [L]
```

Then in your links you add something like:

```
<a href="http://exampel.com/services/35/operating-systems-windows.html">operating systems windows</a>
```

Note, that you should not use spaces inside an url, so in this case I assume those will be replaced with an `-` character.

It may also be better to narrow down allowed characters and numbers in your rewrite rule:

```
# will match services/<number>/<string>.html
# the NC flag states that the rule is case insensitive
RewriteRule services/([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+)\.html$ /services.php?prod_id=$1&prod_url=$2 [NC,L]
```